# What do you call this functional language feature?

Tags: function, j, tacit-programming

ok, embarrassing enough, I posted [code that I need explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445782/finding-closest-match-in-collection-of-numbers#449148). Specifically, it first chains absolute value and subtraction together, then tacks on a sort, all the while not having to mention parameters and arguments at all, because of the presense of "adverbs" that can join these functions "verbs"

What (non-APL-type) languages support this kind of no-arguments function composition (I have the vague idea it ties in strongly to the concepts of monad/dyad and rank, but its hard to get a particularly easy-to-understand picture just from reading Wikipedia) and what do I call this concept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to [pointfree](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) style; this works though composition and currying. Functional languages such as Haskell and ML use this.

Concatenative programming languages like Joy, Factor, and Cat also have these "adverbs."