# data structure to find values in an interval

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a multithreaded simulation code doing some calculation in discrete time steps. So for each time stamp I have a set of variables which I want to store and access later on.

Now my question is:

**What is a good/the best data structure given following conditions?:**

- has to be thread-safe (so I guess a ordered dictionary might be best here). I have one thread writing data, other threads only read it.
- I want to find data later given a time interval which is not necessarily a multiple of the time-step size.
  E.g.: I simulate values from `t=0` to `t=10` in steps of `1`. If I get a request for all data in the range of `t=5.6` to `t=8.1`, I want to get the simulated values such that the requested times are within the returned time range. In this case all data from `t=5` to `t=9`.
- the time-step size can vary from run to run. It is constant within a run, so the created data set has always a consistent time-step size. But I might want to restart simulation with a better time resolution.
- the amount of time stamps which are calculated might be rather large (up to a million may be)

From searching through the net I get the impression some tree-like structure implemented as a dictionary might be a good idea, but I would also need some kind of iterator/index to go through the data, since I want to fetch always data from time intervals. I got no real idea how something like that could look like ...

There are posts for [finding a key in a dictionary  close to a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7934547/11470674). But these always include some look up of all the keys in the dictionary, which might not be so cool for a million of keys (that is how I feel at least).

Comment: Look up Sorted Map applications for things like Flight Databases.

Comment: If you can build the data structure in a sorted way (or sort it later) _and_ you know the step-size, you can even use a list. The indices of the desired interval can be calculated then.

Comment: @Wups - Thanks! That actually is a nice idea and I went for it. Works well so far.