# Find the closest match of a list in a list containing lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list with two elements like this:

```
list_a = [27.666521, 85.437447]
```

and another list like this:

```
big_list = [[27.666519, 85.437477], [27.666460, 85.437622], ...]
```

And I want to find the closest match of `list_a` within `list_b`.

For example, here the closest match would be `[27.666519, 85.437477]`.

How would I be able to achieve this?

I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445782/finding-closest-match-in-collection-of-numbers) for finding the closest match of a string in an array but was unable to reproduce it similarly for the above mentioned problem.

P.S.The elements in the list are the co-ordinates of points on the earth.

Comment: Which norm do you want to use to define the "distance"?

Comment: if you want to do this often, you should think about a better data structure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your question, it's hard to tell how you want to measure the distance, so I simply assume you mean Euclidean distance.

You can use the `key` parameter to `min()`:

```
from functools import partial

def distance_squared(x, y):
    return (x[0] - y[0])**2 + (x[1] - y[1])**2

print min(big_list, key=partial(distance_squared, list_a))
```

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds, and yours is more generic. I love the use of partial. Have a well-deserved upvote!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have mentioned in my question that the distance between the points was the distance between two co-ordinates on earth, but I guess that for a very small difference in distance  it wouldn't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- You intend to make this type query more than once on the same *list of lists*
- Both the query *list* and the lists in your *list of lists* represent points in a n-dimensional euclidean space (here: a 2-dimensional space, unlike GPS positions that come from a spherical space).

This reads like a [nearest neighbor search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm). Probably you should take into consideration a library dedicated for this, like [scikits.ann](http://scikits.appspot.com/ann).

Example:

```
import scikits.ann as ann
import numpy as np
k = ann.kdtree(np.array(big_list))
indices, distances = k.knn(list_a, 1)
```

This uses euclidean distance internally. You should make sure, that the distance measure you apply complies your idea of proximity.

You might also want to have a look on [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), which is another data structure that you could apply to avoid the brute force minimum search through your entire list of lists.