# Given a list of strings find each of its string's closest match (edit distance) in another big list of strings

Tags: python, knn, trie, suffix-tree, edit-distance

I have a list of strings `small_list = ['string1', 'this is string 2', ...]` and a larger list of strings `big_list = ['is string 2', 'some other string 3', 'string 1', ...]`. I want to find the string that is closest by edit distance for all of the strings in small_list in big_list.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630031/find-the-closest-match-of-a-list-in-a-list-containing-lists/) which does the same with numbers.

Solution 1 that I tried:

```
from difflib import get_close_matches
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.now()
print(get_close_matches(str(small_list.iloc[0]), big_list.values.astype(str), n=3, cutoff=0.7))
b = datetime.datetime.now()
c = b - a
print(c.seconds)
```

But for my dataset and for that one record, it took me `834 seconds`. `len(big_list) = 27989793` and `len(small_list) = 9329931` so performance is of at most importance.

Solution 2 that I tried:

```
s = str(small_list.iloc[0])
a = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in big_list:
    m = editdistance.eval(i[0], s)
    if m < min:
        min = m
        i_s = i
b = datetime.datetime.now()
c = b - a
print(c.seconds)
```

For this I used the [editdistance](https://pypi.org/project/editdistance/) package that is implemented efficiently in C++ and I got a time of 48 seconds.

To improve on the above solutions I require that I not exhaustively go over all the values in big_list. I'm looking for ways to do the same.

One of the approaches that I came up with was creating a trie (or some kind of a suffix-tree) with the concatenated big_list of strings and query that trie to find matches. Due to lack of experience in this, was hoping for some package suggestions or some code that I could start off of. Another approach would be to modify the KNN algorithm that uses edit distance as a metric. Any sklearn or other packages that do this?

Expected output: `[3, 1, ...]` which are positions of the closest match in big_list.

Comment: You can use cosine distance or the Jaccard similarity coefficient. You should try sklearn, sklearn have a module name metrics which help you to compute these two metrics and more [please take a look here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics.pairwise)

Comment: @Prune I have edited the question to show my work. Kindly consider removing your down vote.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I can use those with string datatypes? An example may be?

Comment: Much better.  I also removed my closure vote.

Comment: You need to vectorize the elements of your lists and then compute the distances between the elements of the lists.

Comment: I still quite don't get how vectorizing would be done. Even if it were converted to numbers, would the locality (based on the edit distance) be conserved by the final vectors? If so how?

Comment: @user281989 did you find any solutions ?